# Storing SSH passphrases in the login keychain instead of Local Items

Tags: macos, keychain, ssh

If I:

- Use `UseKeychain yes` in `~/.ssh/config`
- Use `ssh-add -K`

My SSH key passphrase is stored in my keychain as expected, however, when I check Keychain Access, the stored passphrase is in my `iCloud`/`Local Items` keychain.

Is there a way for me to choose which keychain it is stored in/have it in `login` instead? I would prefer to have it on a local keychain, as I do not use the same SSH key on multiple machines.

I am on macOS 12.0.1